# gitweb on nginx ...to unix:/tmp/fcgiwrap.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting

Tags: nginx, git, fastcgi, fcgi

I've gone through the answers provided in similar posts but I am still getting a `Connection refused` error when trying to connect to `git.example.com`.

The exact nginx error message is as follows

```
2019/11/05 17:16:09 [error] 12175#12175: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/fcgiwrap.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: git.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/fcgiwrap.sock:", host: "git.example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/"
```

`ls -l /tmp/fcgiwrap.sock` gives

`srwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 0 Jul 3 00:56 /tmp/fcgiwrap.sock`

I've given write permission to the socket file just in case via `chmod g+w /tmp/fcgiwrap.sock`.

`ps aux | grep nginx` gives the following

```
root     11203 0.0 0.1 47572 1412 ?    Ss 07:17 0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data 11204 0.0 0.6 47788 6116 ?    S  07:17 0:01 nginx: worker process
www-data 11205 0.0 0.3 47572 2856 ?    S  07:17 0:02 nginx: worker process
www-data 11206 0.0 0.4 47572 5632 ?    S  07:17 0:02 nginx: worker process
www-data 11207 0.0 0.0 47572 2856 ?    S  07:17 0:02 nginx: worker process
pi       11996 0.0 0.0 4733  576  ?    S  07:17 0:01 grep nginx
```

Nginx user is `www-data`. I suspect it's my nginx conf file. Note that I have both `git.example.com` and `example.com` listening on port 443, but I have an `A` record for `git` prefix in my DNS settings.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name git.example.com;

  location ~ ^.*\.git/(HEAD|info/refs|objects/info/.*|git-(upload|receive)-pack)$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/example/git;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /usr/share/nginx/example/.gitpasswd;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/fcgiwrap.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $uri;
    fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT  /usr/share/nginx/example/git;
    fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
  location /index.cgi {
    root /usr/share/gitweb;
    include fastcgi_params;
    gzip off;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $uri;
    fastcgi_param GITWEB_CONFIG /etc/gitweb.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/fcgiwrap.sock;
  }
  location / {
    root /usr/share/gitweb;
    index index.cgi;
  }

  ssl_certificate /.../fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate /.../privkey.pem;


}
```

Note that I have `fcgiwrap` and `spawn-fcgi` installed and running albeit giving me a Setting locale failed error -- it automatically falls back to locale ("en_GB.UTF-8").

**UPDATE**

[here](https://forums.otterhub.org/viewtopic.php?t=19852) it states the error means `fcgiwrap` isn't running on that socket file.

I've followed [this nginx tutorial](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fcgiwrap/) to include `/usr/share/doc/fcgiwrap/examples/nginx.conf` in my `conf` server block  where `fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/fcgiwrap.sock` in `nginx.conf` file... but still no dice.

**What I've tried so far**

1. `gitweb.cgi` was created by `root` but I've given it read permission with `chmod +x`.
2. restarting `fcgiwrap`, `nginx`
3. Someone said it could be a `php-fpm` issue...so I made sure its conf in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` `listen` parameter was assigned to the correct sock `/tmp/php7.0-fpm.sock` that allowed read/write for `www-data`

Comment: Have you ensured that SELinux/AppArmor are not interfering? What does `netstat -nlp | grep 443` have to show?

Comment: I had to run it as `sudo`. It gives `tcp      0      0  0.0.0.0:443      0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    12904/nginx: master`.

Comment: Yes, sorry -- I presumed you were already su'd as root. Did you check for SELinux/AppArmor? `sudo getenforce` for SELinux and `sudo aa-status` for AppArmor.

Comment: No worries. I tried your commands, but both gives me `command not found`.